# WPF GroupBox ControlTemplate : How to apply a Style only to elements in the Header?

Tags: wpf, header, styles, controltemplate, groupbox

I'm trying to make a `ControlTemplate` for a `GroupBox` such that if a `TextBlock` is declared in the `Header` its `Background` should be set to yellow.

The problem is that, although I define a style for `TextBlock`s in the `ContentPresenter` for the `Header`, it's not applied except on those `TextBlock`s which are autogenerated by WPF.

Here is the code :

```
<Window
  x:Class="TestHeaderTemplate.Window1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  Title="Window1"
  SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
  <Window.Resources>    
    <Style
      TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
      <Setter
        Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate
            TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">            
            <Border
              Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
              BorderBrush="Black"
              BorderThickness="1">
              <StackPanel>
                <Border
                  Margin="0,0,0,5"
                  BorderThickness="5"
                  BorderBrush="LightBlue"
                  >
                  <ContentPresenter
                    ContentSource="Header">
                    <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                      <Style
                        TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter
                          Property="Background"
                          Value="Yellow" />
                      </Style>
                    </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                  </ContentPresenter>
                </Border>
                <ContentPresenter
                  ContentSource="Content" />
              </StackPanel>
            </Border>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBox
      Text="All TextBoxes in a GroupBox's Header should be yellow, whether declared or autogenerated." />
    <GroupBox
      x:Name="firstGroupBox"
      Margin="5"
      Header="I am a TextBlock autogenerated by WPF. Since I'm in the Header, I should be yellow.">
        <TextBlock
          Text="I'm a TextBlock declared in the content of the GroupBox. I should NOT be yellow." />      
    </GroupBox>
    <GroupBox
      x:Name="secondGroupbox"
      Margin="5"
      >
      <HeaderedContentControl.Header>      
          <TextBlock
            x:Name="notStyledTextBlock"
            Text="I'm a TextBlock declared in the header. I should be yellow since I'm in the header."
            VerticalAlignment="Center" />          
      </HeaderedContentControl.Header>
      <TextBlock
        Text="I'm declared in the content so I should not be yellow." />
    </GroupBox>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

As you can see if you try, the background of the `TextBlock` named `notStyledTextBlock` in the second `GroupBox` is not yellow, which means the style defined in the resources of the `ContentPresenter` in the `ControlTemplate` is not applied.

Surprisingly, the one that was autogenerated by WPF as a container for the header text of the first `GroupBox` has its background yellow.

What can I do to make it so my style is applied to the `notStyledTextBlock` `TextBlock`?

Comment: Setting the background of the Border in your style to Yellow would fix it in your example, but would add a yellow background to non textblocks used in headers as well. I upvoted HCL's answer since I believe the explanation he was given, it is by design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had also problems with GroupBoxes and ContentPresenter. I have posted a question and because no answer was given I investigated myself a little. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063264/contentpresenter-within-controltemplate-cannot-change-attached-dependency-propert/3068659#3068659) answer, maybe its the same issue (Additional info: I have not posted my real problem-code but a simplified example that could be used to reproduce).

Comment: You're right it's kind of the same problem : especially this part : "If the Content of ContentControl is already a WPF-Element, it is created before using it in the ContenPresenter" <-- that's probably why the style is not applied to the 2nd TextBlock. Yet I can't see a way to tell WPF that I want some style applied only to the Header. ControlTemplate.Resources doesn't help since the style would be applied to all TextBlocks (both in header and content). I wish there was a ContentPresenter.ContentStyle property...

Comment: I've marked your answer as accepted since I haven't been able to make any progress on the issue. Thanks also to WallStreet Programmer for the support.